# Jedi module is not found (deoplete)

Tags: neovim, python, plugin-deoplete

`:checkhealth` shows neither errors nor warnings about jedi:

```
health#jedi#check
====================================
## jedi
#### Jedi-vim debug information


##### jedi-vim version


- jedi-vim git version: a17b033
- jedi git submodule status:  3b7106ae71cb7bd3431101d169a0110ee0c179aa        pythonx/jedi (v0.17.2)
- parso git submodule status:  c864ca60d1a2f36524a4f79013a7de223e65e19d       pythonx/parso (v0.6.0)

##### Global Python

Using Python version 3 to access Jedi.
- global sys.executable: /usr/bin/python3
- global sys.version: 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26), [GCC 9.3.       0]
- global site module: /usr/lib/python3.8/site.py


##### Jedi

- path: /root/.config/nvim/plugged/jedi-vim/pythonx/jedi/jedi/__init__.py
- version: 0.17.2

##### Jedi environment: <SameEnvironment: 3.8.2 in /usr>


- executable: /usr/bin/python3
- sys_path:
    - /usr/lib/python38.zip
    - /usr/lib/python3.8
    - /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
    - /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
    - /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

##### Known environments


- <Environment: 3.8.2 in /usr> (/usr/bin/python3.8)



##### Settings



g:jedi#usages_command = ',o' (default: '<leader>n')
g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = ',a' (default: '<leader>g')
g:jedi#goto_command = ',d' (default: '<leader>d')
g:jedi#completions_enabled = 0 (default: 1)


  omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
    Last set from /usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/html.vim line 
  completeopt=menu,noinsert
    Last set from ~/.config/arch-chronicle/nvim-fisa/init.vim
```

As soon as I open a Python file, I see a message:

```
[deoplete] jedi module is not found. You need to install it..
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: I can see you have the jedi-vim plug-in installed... But do you also have the [deoplete-jedi](https://github.com/deoplete-plugins/deoplete-jedi) one? That plug-in requires the jedi module in Python. From NeoVim, can you run `:py3 import jedi` successfully?

Comment: Yes `deoplete-jedi` installed, `:py3 import jedi` runs succesfully. At least, silently :)

Comment: Besides, how am I supposed to `Use :messages / see above for error details.`? I cannot see more than one line, no matter what.

Comment: I assume you’re using this computer as root ? Otherwise I would suggest that the location of the installation files in /root/ could be an issue

Comment: Yes, it's a remote setup. Absolutely everything else in my `nvim` configuration works just fine. I hope my trouble is not lethal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case I had to run this command:

```
pip3 install --user jedi
```

Comment: Thanks! Or `# apt install python3-jedi`, for me. So `:checkhealth` is not to be relied upon in a simple case like this. An important lesson!

Comment: `pipx install jedi` is also nice.

Comment: Apologies: `pipx` *can't* install `jedi` because it's a library without an executable. `pipx install jedi` raises [this error](https://github.com/pypa/pipx/blob/6e1907bc9e8f8d0741d825911e72c1f8551e1aca/src/pipx/commands/common.py#L359-L363).